# Не привязывается домен от freenom.com к google sites

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте у меня не получается привязать домен от freenom.com к google sites вроде бы всё делаю как показано в инструкции https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ly-FmufsGc&t=186s но в  Search Console при попытке подтвердить право собственности пишут "Не удалось подтвердить право собственности" Причина ошибки:"Не удалось найти ваш домен. Проверьте, правильно ли он указан."
Помогите разобраться в чём проблема?

Comment: а почему бы не воспользоваться [документацией](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/9068867?hl=ru) от владельца инфраструктуры вместо просмотра развлекательных роликов?

Comment: Там поверхностные инструкции